# Distinguishing the moving and fixed DIVs in html based on CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am learning some frontend development and came across [this webpage example](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/examples/positioning2.html)

It's a simple web page with the body made solely out of `divs`

This below is a fixed div, when I say fixed I mean when I resize the browser from the bottom or the left, right the div is not adjusted and it goes out of view.

```
<div style="background-color: #292929; color: white; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 80px; width: 100px; height: 300px; padding: 5px; padding-right: 20px;">This will be the navigation 'column', which will run down the left of the page.</div>
```

while the one below is moving

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; bottom: 100px; background-color: #0099CC; padding: 5px; color: white; border: 5px white groove; font-size: 13pt;">I could go on, but I think you see the brilliance of these things.</div>
```

**both** the divs have **absolute** positioning but the first or the fixed `div` has positioning for top defined as `
The only difference that I see is that first or the fixed as

```
top: 80px  \\for fixed div
```

while it's

```
bottom: 100px \\for the moving div
```

My question is why only bottom attribute in css for this div puts it in another layer while top doesn't do the same for the fixed div? Or maybe there is something else to it?

Comment: it's simple, the first is aligned by the top, so when you change the browser(window) top border it moves together (while the other stay parked). The second one (blue) is aligned by the bottom, so when you resize the window moving the bottom edge, it moves together (while the first stay parked).

Comment: @freestock.tk did you really try moving down the top border? for me it stays parked in any case.

Comment: @Airudh I made this gif I hope it can be helpful [**click here**](https://i.gyazo.com/0fc2b6405b1a3311ac4d731f523f601b.gif) (gif of my screen while I drag the window's top edge resizing it) notice the blue div stay on its place because the bottom of the page isnt moving, only the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning is dependent on its parent element. If the div is nested within another div with any positioning besides static(the default) then it will be displayed absolute to that div not the body or page. I am not sure what you mean by "layering". If you want to layer divs you can use z-index to put one above the other.

EDIT:
The top left corner of a browser always remain at 0,0 the only thing that changes on a resize is the bottom right coordinates

Comment: my question is why the divs in the shade of yellow..don't move at all when you resize the window?

Comment: The bottom positioned div will always be 100 pixels from the bottom because it is absolutely positioned if you resize the browser height it will follow the browser up and remain 100 pixels above the bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/fvtjyppf/

Comment: but why isn't the same observed with div having `top: 80px` attribute on being resized from the the top? it doesn't go anywhere. :|

Comment: The top left corner of a browser always remain at 0,0 the only thing that changes on a resize is the bottom right coordinates.

Comment: I think I see what your wanting to do now instead of absolute positioning use fixed positioning that. when you scroll it will always be relative to the viewport.

Comment: so as I thought it was the bottom property that could only move the divs up on being resized from the bottom...now I get it that the top left being the `origin` point keeps everything fixed relative to it. that was what I was looking for....you can edit your answer and add this..I will mark it as the right answer.